# std::map not behaving properly as std:unordered_map

Tags: std, unordered-map, stdmap

I am trying to solve this problem  : https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/

My idea: is to use 2  hash table (map): one for negative values & zeros , one for positive values.

a+b+c=0  --> a+b = -C

So iterate over the negative values , check for each positive value if the negative value exists -> then we have a 3sum.

The problem that I get is  :

I am iterating over a map which has the frequency of occurrences of numbers inside a vector (in the function threeSum ) &
I decrement  a number's frequency (number = -1 ) to 0:
Then I call a function which is supposed to check if the number is there or not;
But it's frequency is still 1 !!
**If I use unordered_map , it works !**

```cpp
// vector::push_back
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;


struct CountStruct{
    
    int element1,element2;
    int count1,count2;
};

void keepOriginalCount (map<int,int> &positive_sign, map<int,int> &negative_and_zero_sign, const CountStruct & originalCount)
{
    if (originalCount.element1<0)
    {
        negative_and_zero_sign[originalCount.element1]=originalCount.count1;
    }
    else if (originalCount.element1>0)
    {
        positive_sign[originalCount.element1]=originalCount.count1;
    }
    
    if (originalCount.element2<0)
    {
        negative_and_zero_sign[originalCount.element2]=originalCount.count2;
    }
    else if (originalCount.element2>0)
    {
        positive_sign[originalCount.element2]=originalCount.count2;
    }
        
}

bool findElement (map<int,int> &positive_sign, map<int,int> &negative_and_zero_sign, const int  element ,const bool & hasZero)
{
    cout<<"findElement: element="<<element<<endl;
    
    if (element<0)
    {
        if(negative_and_zero_sign[element]>0)
        {
                cout<<"findElement: negative_and_zero_sign[element]="<<negative_and_zero_sign[element]<<endl;

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (element>0)
    {
        if(positive_sign[element]>0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if( hasZero == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

void fillMaps (map<int,int> &positive_sign, map<int,int> &negative_and_zero_sign,vector<int>& nums , bool & hasZero , int &zeroCount)
{

        for ( unsigned int i =0 ; i< nums.size();i++)
        {
            if(nums[i]<0)
            {
                                cout<<"nums[i]"<<nums[i]<<endl;
                negative_and_zero_sign[nums[i]]++;
            }else if(nums[i]>0){
                cout<<"nums[i]"<<nums[i]<<endl;
                positive_sign[nums[i]]++;
            }
            else
            {
                                cout<<"nums[i]"<<nums[i]<<endl;
                hasZero=true;
                zeroCount++;
            }
        }
}

    vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {
        
            vector<vector<int>> result;
    map<int,int> positive_sign;
    map<int,int> negative_and_zero_sign;
    bool hasZero = false;
    int zeroCount=0;
    
    fillMaps(positive_sign,negative_and_zero_sign,nums,hasZero,zeroCount);
    
    for(auto& itNegative : negative_and_zero_sign) {
    
        
            if (itNegative.second <=0)
            continue;
        
        CountStruct originalCount;
        originalCount.element1 = itNegative.first;
        originalCount.count1 = itNegative.second;
        
        cout<<"---------originalCount.element1 "<<originalCount.element1 <<endl;
        cout<<"---******itNegative.first "<<itNegative.first <<endl;
        cout<<"Before---******itNegative.second "<<itNegative.second <<endl;
        
        itNegative.second--;
        
        cout<<"After---******itNegative.second "<<itNegative.second <<endl;
        
        cout<<"-----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        
        for(auto& itPositive : positive_sign) {

            if (itPositive.second <=0)
            continue;
        
            originalCount.element2 = itPositive.first;
            originalCount.count2 = itPositive.second;
        
            cout<<"+++******itPositive.first "<<itPositive.first <<endl;
            cout<<"+++******itPositive.second "<<itPositive.second <<endl;
        
            itPositive.second = itPositive.second - 1;
            
            
            cout<<"+++******After : itPositive.second "<<itPositive.second <<endl;
            
        //  cout<<"--------originalCount.element2 "<<originalCount.element2 <<endl;
            
            if (findElement (positive_sign,negative_and_zero_sign,(originalCount.element1+originalCount.element2)*-1,hasZero))
            {
                cout<<"Yahoo , element found"<<endl;
                vector <int> temp;
                temp.push_back(originalCount.element1);
                temp.push_back(originalCount.element2);
                temp.push_back( (originalCount.element1+originalCount.element2)*-1);
                result.push_back(temp);
            }
            
            keepOriginalCount(positive_sign,negative_and_zero_sign, originalCount);
        
        }

        
    }
    
    if(zeroCount >=3)
    {
        vector <int> temp;
        temp.push_back(0);
        temp.push_back(0);
        temp.push_back(0);
        result.push_back(temp);
    }
    
    return result ; 
    }



int main ()
{
vector<int> testV = {1,2,-2,-1};

auto x = threeSum(testV);

  return 0;
}
```

output : [[-1,2,-1]]  !! Should be null

Works with unordered_map

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which shows the error. And clearly describe what is the expected result and what is the result you observe

Comment: Sure , I will do that

Comment: FYI - `if (positive_sign[element]>0) { return true; } else { return false; }` can be better written as `return positive_sign[element] > 0;`.

Comment: @derpirscher , I added more code

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not caused by `unordered_map` vs `map`. It's just a random coincidence with your current testvector and the (in principle) random order an `unordered_map` is traversed.

The real problem in your algorithm is, that you are restoring the original count for ALL values in the inner loop of your `threeSum` method.

Consider the following situation:

- `itNegative` is currently pointing at the element `-1` which has a frequency of `1`.
- you keep that frequency of `1` in `originalElement.count1` and decrement the `itNegative.second--`, ie the frequency is `0`
- now the inner loop starts to run

  - `itPositive` points (for instance) to the element `1` which has a frequency of `1`
  - you keep that frequency of `1` in `originalElement.count2` and decrement the `itPositive.second--`, ie the frequency is `0`
  - you search for `0` in both maps, but don't find anything
  - now you call `keepOriginalCount` which resets ALL frequencies to their original value (ie for both `-1` and `1`)
  - in the next iteration of the inner loop `itPositive` points to `2`, `itNegative` still points to `-1`.
  - you now search for `-1` (`(2 + -1) * -1`) and you find it, because `keepOriginalCount` from the prior step reset the frequency of `-1` to `1`.

The solution is, not to use `keepOriginalCount` in the inner loop, but just resetting the frequency of the element `itPositive` is currently pointing at. Reset the frequency of `itNegative` only after the inner loop is finished and you are advancing to the next element in the outer loop. You could even skip resetting the frequency of `itNegative` at all, because you already checked all possible combinations, where it could be part of a solution.

```
for(auto& itNegative : negative_and_zero_sign) {
    if (itNegative.second <=0)
        continue;
    
    CountStruct originalCount;
    originalCount.element1 = itNegative.first;
    originalCount.count1 = itNegative.second;
    
    itNegative.second--;  //decrement the frequency of element1
        
    for(auto& itPositive : positive_sign) {
        if (itPositive.second <=0)
            continue;
    
        originalCount.element2 = itPositive.first;
        originalCount.count2 = itPositive.second;
    
        itPositive.second--; //decrement the frequency of element2
        if (findElement (positive_sign,negative_and_zero_sign,(originalCount.element1+originalCount.element2) * -1,hasZero))
        {
            cout<<"Yahoo , element found  " <<  originalCount.element1 << " "<<  originalCount.element2 << endl;
            vector <int> temp;
            temp.push_back(originalCount.element1);
            temp.push_back(originalCount.element2);
            temp.push_back( (originalCount.element1+originalCount.element2) * -1);
            result.push_back(temp);
        }
        itPositive.second++;  //reset only the frequency of element2
    
    }
    itNegative.second++; //reset only the frequency of element1
}
```